# How to sum up point value within associated geometry?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've got two faces raycasting from theirs points against cube's geometry.

If there is a hit, then a whole face should inherit hit status, so left face with one point inside cube should return "1" (in Viewer output it is "1" for a point and "0" for a face in yellow framed area).

In order to do it, I should calculate total amount of hits on each casting face or mesh island.

With no luck I tried *Transfer Attribute* node and *Attribute Statistics*.

[image]

Comment: @quellenform, question was about accumulating points' "hit status" on a source polygon. So, Accumulate Field node solved this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Accumulate Field** allows to collect data within specified geometry groups input - *Group Index*.

I want to get total amount of ray hits on each source face, so have to get proper indices first (*Capture Attribute* with face option) or *Mesh Island* ID for a whole separated geometry and plug it to *Group Index*.

You can accumulate not only points, but edges and faces as well, just make sure *Group Index* is valid.

[image]